# TCPDF Output() function method not working if script is called through AJAX, but works if script is called in browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I'm using TCPDF to dynamically generate PDF documents. I am using jQuery's `$.ajax()` method to call the PDF generation script (`pdf_output.php`) which saves the PDF to the server's file system using TCPDF's `Output()` method:

```
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output("Account Summary - ".$client_data['name'].".pdf", 'F');
```

This works great when calling the PHP script directly from the browser, but doesn't work when calling the script via AJAX. The script executes (I can print `$_POST` variables from the PHP script into the developer console via `echo json_encode()` and the script returns a value at the end), but the PDF never is saved to the server's filesystem.

However, if I run the `pdf_output.php` script directly in the browser, it works!

Here's how I'm calling the output script:

**Javascript:**

```
function trigger(client_number, month, year)
{
  $("#selected_client").val(client_number);
  $('#cash_recon').modal('show'); 

  var function_name = "_generate_pdf_closing";
  var data =
      { 
        function_name: function_name,
        client_id: client_number,
        month: month,
        year: year
      }
  console.dir(data);
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/inspect.php",
      data: data,
      success: function (data) 
      {
        console.log("Success callback executed!");
      },

});
```

**Inspect.php**

```
<?php
include_once('../includes/data_functions.php');
$function_name = $_REQUEST['function_name'];
switch ($function_name) 
{
    case '_generate_pdf_closing':
        print (generate_pdf_closing($_REQUEST['client_id'], $_REQUEST['month'], $_REQUEST['year']));
        break;
}
?>
```

**generate_pdf_closing() from data_functions.php:**

```
function generate_pdf_closing($client_id, $month, $year){

  include("../pdf/pdf_output.php");
  return $result;

}
```

To clarify: If I call the `pdf_output.php` file in the browser, it generates and saves the PDF to the server perfectly. However, if I call the pdf_output.php script via AJAX, it appears to execute but the PDF is never generated/saved to the server.

**Ideas? Any help is appreciated :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved! The issue was that we had to use an absolute path when defining the file location of the `Output()` method.